# Order By In Pivot Select Statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

This is my statement I need `Order By date` but I can't do this any help please

My code

```
PROCEDURE [sal_pivottable_day_plan]
AS
    DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), 
            @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
            @DtFrom date, @DtTo date

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(sal_day_plan_0015.MyDate) FROM sal_day_plan_0015 

    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')
    SET @query = 'SELECT dealers_sril, dealers_name, stop_value, hanging_value, dealers_balanc, paid_val_motkhrat, ' + @cols + ' 
                  FROM ( 
                         SELECT dealers_sril, dealers_name, stop_value, hanging_value, dealers_balanc, paid_val_motkhrat, paid_val_between,MyDate
                        FROM  sal_day_plan_0015 
                        )x
                   PIOVT
                   ( 
                     min(paid_val_between)for MyDate in (' + @cols + ') 
                   ) p'             

    EXEC(@query)            

    RETURN 0
```

Comment: what it returns?. what you need to return say clearly

Answer (score 1):

You can alias `',' + QUOTENAME(sal_day_plan_0015.MyDate) as c` and order by that column:

```
PROCEDURE [sal_pivottable_day_plan]
AS
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),@DtFrom date ,@DtTo date

    SELECT @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(sal_day_plan_0015.MyDate) AS c FROM sal_day_plan_0015 
    ORDER BY c
    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')

    SET @query = 'SELECT dealers_sril, dealers_name, stop_value, hanging_value, dealers_balanc, paid_val_motkhrat, ' + @cols + ' 
                  FROM ( 
                         SELECT dealers_sril, dealers_name, stop_value, hanging_value, dealers_balanc, paid_val_motkhrat, paid_val_between,MyDate
                        FROM  sal_day_plan_0015 
                        )x
                   PIVOT
                   ( 
                     min(paid_val_between)for MyDate in (' + @cols + ') 
                   ) p'             
EXEC(@query)            
RETURN 0
```

PS: you have error in `PIVOT` keyword.